# Flutter Launch Icon Doesn't Change

Tags: android, flutter, icons

I found lots of questions about this but I have a different problem. The launch icon is not refreshing on a specific phone with Android 10. I tried to changed it and installing it again and does work. The good thing is that on another phone with Android 7 works perfectly fine, even changing the icon.

It's clearly a phone cache problem. The Same flutter app on two different devices present different icons.

This didn't worked:

1. Uninstalling the App
2. Shutting down the phone
3. Turning on the phone
4. Installing the app

Tried with Visual Studio Code, Android Studio and the Cmd console, it doesn't work. I hoped that the release installation will work but nope.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please implementing your code here so I can guess what the thing is going on your with your app ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

My Android manifest has:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

For Android 10 it was taking the ic_launcher_round, and for the Android 7 the ic_launcher. I would like to know if there is some kind of configuration to change this or it is an Android fixed thing.